# Discrete time survival analysis with varying length event windows

Tags: survival, discrete-data

I have data that appears very well-suited to discrete-time survival analysis, in that each subject has a consecutive sequence of observations from its entry into the system until its exit, and I'm interested in determining the likelihood that a subject will leave the system in the next time period.  The catch is that the time periods are not uniform in length.  There are several possible ways I can imagine addressing this problem.  The top two that come to mind are:
1.  increasing the granularity by further discretizing my time intervals to the minimum length
2.  leaving the individual time periods as is, but weighting each period in the analysis by its actual length
I prefer the second option to the first one.  My questions are:
1.  Is the second option acceptable?
2.  Which of the two options is preferable?
3.  Is there a better third option?
Thank you!

Comment: Why is this a problem to begin with Talbot?

Comment: I mean what is the issue with having varying length?

Comment: Thank you for responding, B_Miner.  It seems to me that there is an implicit assumption of equivalence of time points in discrete time survival analysis, i.e., there is no "internal structure" that affects the likelihood of whether the outcome will take place or not.  Now it's possible for a given setup that different lengths wouldn't affect the likelihood of the outcome, but if the length can vary a lot, from a week to a year, then the chances are pretty good that, all external factors being equal, the event has a higher chance of occurring in the long interval than the short one.

Comment: Paul Allison's book, "Survival Analysis Using SAS, A Practical Guide" Second Edition, page 249, suggests using the length of the interval as a covariate.  However, that would require prior knowledge of the length of the interval for scoring purposes, which my setup won't have.  So I'm looking for a way to acknowledge the varying lengths in creating the model that doesn't require foreknowledge in scoring.  Right now we're leaning towards the further discretization option -- I was trying to avoid that, but I've started to lean toward it.

Comment: If the concern is as a predictive model - which I assume from "scoring" I believe (from a SAS class based on Will Potts) that this is not a problem. Am I correct also this is a truncated situation - meaning at the time the model is created, you are training on customers (as example, not sure your application) that are at some time t >0? Some alive for 20 weeks, some 100 weeks etc?

Comment: If this is the case, can you not just set time t equal to tenure for those customers?

Comment: Hi B_Miner (and others), thank you for the continued discussion.  My setup is a pretty typical discrete-time survival analysis, with the exception that the natural periods in the data have varying time lengths.  You may not be convinced from my description that this issue could affect the modeling results, but Allison has devoted two pages of his book to discuss the issue (including a setup under which the varying length intervals would NOT affect the outcome), so at least he recognizes the relevance.  Sadly, his discussion does not apply to my data, for reasons I tried to make clear above.

Comment: Maybe post an example of the data to make more clear the issue. Good luck!